# NVD3 scatter plot not showing

Tags: python, django, d3.js, nvd3.js, scatter-plot

I was trying to try the nvd3 scatter plot example myself. I am not getting any error, but the chart is not populating.

I got a blank web page when I try to get to the screen. Even my existing other contents are gone. Did anyone manage to get the scatter plot up and running? I would really appreciate if you could share a working example.

```
#html
<script>            
    $(document).ready(function(){           

        nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
                .showDistX(true)    //showDist, when true, will display those little distribution lines on the axis.
                .showDistY(true)

                .color(d3.scale.category10().range());   

  //Axis settings
  chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));
  chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'));



  var myData = randomData(4,40);
  d3.select('#chart svg')
      .datum(myData)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});

    /**************************************
 * Simple test data generator
 */
function randomData(groups, points) { //# groups,# points per group
  var data = [],
      shapes = ['circle', 'cross', 'triangle-up', 'triangle-down', 'diamond', 'square'],
      random = d3.random.normal();

  for (i = 0; i < groups; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: 'Group ' + i,
      values: []
    });

    for (j = 0; j < points; j++) {
      data[i].values.push({
        x: random()
      , y: random()
      , size: Math.random()   //Configure the size of each scatter point
      , shape: (Math.random() > 0.95) ? shapes[j % 6] : "circle"  //Configure the shape of each scatter point.
      });
    }
  }

  return data;
}

    });
```

Comment: Try to put your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Its easy to debug and help you.

Comment: Sounds like you probably have a JS error. What do you see in the console? Agree JSFiddle or Plunkr would help.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter how simple is your graphic, it just doesn't show.
Maybe it just incompatible with the new version of python.
I'm using python 3.6

It generates the code, all the css's and j's are working fine, according developer tools of google.
But still, it doesn't show.

```
data_piechart_container=[
    {"values": [
      {"label": "Apple", "value": 52}, 
      {"label": "Apricot", "value": 48}, 
      {"label": "Avocado", "value": 160}, 
      {"label": "Banana", "value": 94}, 
      {"label": "Boysenberries", "value": 75}, 
      {"label": "Blueberries", "value": 71}, 
      {"label": "Dates", "value": 490},
      {"label": "Grapefruit", "value": 82}, 
      {"label": "Kiwi", "value": 46}, 
      {"label": "Lemon", "value": 17}
     ], "key": "Serie 1"}];

nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.pieChart();
    chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 20, left: 60});
    var datum = data_piechart_container[0].values;

    chart.color(d3.scale.category20().range());

chart.tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
    var x = String(key);
        var y = String(graph.point.y);
        tooltip_str = '<center><b>'+x+'</b></center>' + y;
        return tooltip_str;
    });
    chart.showLabels(true);

        chart.donut(false);

chart.showLegend(true);

chart
    .x(function(d) { return d.label })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value });
chart.height(450);

d3.select('#piechart_container svg')
    .datum(datum)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .attr('height', 450)
    .call(chart);
});
```